# Clip an ellipse based on two points

Tags: wpf, intersection, ellipse, clip

I want to clip an ellipse based on two points located on the ellipses outline.
The points cannot be used as the corners of the clip rectangle, because the resulting clip area may be too small (middle circle) and the ellipse would be still be fully visible.
What I want is in the right image. How do I determine such a clip rectangle intersecting the ellipse at two given points?

[image]

What I want to achieve, is creating a radial range slider: a slider with two thumbs moving on an elliptic track. I already have most of it, but I want the track to have different colors for the part between the thumbs (inside the range) and the rest. So I thought about putting two ellipses (one red, one green) on top of each other and from the green one only show the part between the points.

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

Comment: Why would you clip it at all, instead of drawing a Path with the resulting geometry?

Comment: I'm not sure I even follow the result you want. The right picture of the three is what you want? How do you know whether you want the left, right, top... bottom or whatever part of the ellipse from the points?

Comment: If you generate a clipping rectangle the same height and width of the ellipse and center the two points on a side, you should get the clipping you want. You will need to ensure that the clipping rectangle is oriented away from the center of the ellipse.